# addition of matrices where column size varies in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find addition of two 2d arrays of different column sizes.
but problem is i don't understand how to declare third array lets say sum[][]
which will hold the result. We have to take arrays from user at run time
and then utilise the dimensions of these array to define sum[].
Example:

```
a=1 2 3
  4 5 6 7
  8 9
b=1 2 3
  4 5 6 7
  8 9
```

How do i find sum?

Answer (score 0):

for your example can do this:

```
    int[][] sum = new int[3][]; // create 2 rows
    sum[0] = new int[3]; // create 3 columns for row 0
    sum[1] = new int[4]; // create 4 columns for row 1
    sum[2] = new int[2]; // create 2 columns for row 2
```

Comment: c=new int[a.length][];
        for(i=0;i<a.length;++i){
        c[i]=new int[a[i].length];
       }